# Alter CSS dynamically using JQuery (or simple Javascript) based on date comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am hand-coding a small calendar of events. All that I wish to display is some basic event information (date, time, location, link to learn more). Since this page will rarely have more than 10-20 events listed at any given time (and only even once or twice per year), I'm not over-engineering it by using a calendar plugin or anything.

All I wish to do is to compare the current date against the HTML5 `<time date=""></time>` attribute and alter CSS on a parent element if the date specified is in the past (by at least one day).

By default the background color of the `<li>` element with class `.event` is white (`#fff`). If the date is in the past, I want the background color on the `<li class='event'>` class to change to grey (`#ddd`) when the page loads.

```html
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Events</title>
<style>
 .event {
  background-color: #fff;
 }
</style>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="row block-grid events">
  <li class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 column event">
   <dl>
    <dt><time date="2016-02-02">Feb 2</time></dt>
    <dd>Boston Public Library at 7:00pm</dd>
    <dd>Book launch</dd>
    <dd>Boston, MA</dd>
    <dd><a href="http://www.bpl.org">More details</a></dd>
   </dl>
  </li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: select said elements, parse date, if date is within x range, add class. seems relatively simple

Comment: do you have any JavaScript to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jQuery solution.  You could use "addClass()" or a similar method for more flexibility.

https://jsfiddle.net/4nb0w2yu/1/

```
$('time').each(function() {
  var submitted_date = new Date($(this).attr('date'));
  var now = new Date();
  console.log(submitted_date.getTime() < now.getTime());
  if (submitted_date.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
    $(this).parent().parent().css('background', 'gray')
  }
});
```

Comment: This totally works--thank you! I tried a few different approaches that approximated this but simply weren't producing results, though they weren't throwing errors, either. (I'm not terribly proficient at Javascript, which I need to work on. I get the logic, but writing the script is not as intuitive for me as it should be.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to get the current date

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth()+1; //Jan = 0
var year = today.getFullYear();
```

Get the `time=""` attribute something like so, I added the class dateColor to the container you will be changing:

`var calDate = document.getElementByClass('dateColor').getAttribute("time");`

Then do a conditional check via JS

After that you can use `toggleClass()` via JQuery to toggle a class with CSS `background-color: whateverColor` on for particular elements if it returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a jQuery example that should do the trick.  I tried to write it as concisely as possible... https://jsfiddle.net/9ekd25L8/3/

```
$("li.event").each(function(){

var dt = new Date();
var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
if ($(month).length <= 1) {
    var month = "0" + month;    
}
var day = dt.getDate();
if ($(day).length <= 1) {
    var day = "0" + day;    
}
var time = dt.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day;
var time2 = $(this).find("time").attr("date");
var monthsplit = time.slice(5,7);
var yearsplit = time.slice(0,4);
var daysplit = time.slice(8,10);
var checkday = time2.slice(8,10);
var checkmonth = time2.slice(5,7);
var checkyear = time2.slice(0,4);
var resultyear = yearsplit - checkyear;
var resultmonth = monthsplit - checkmonth;
var resultday = daysplit - checkday;

if (resultyear == 0 && resultmonth <= 0 && resultday <= 0) {
    $(this).addClass("new");
}
else if (resultyear > 0) {
    $(this).addClass("old");
}
else {
  $(this).addClass("old");
}

 if (resultyear == 0 && resultmonth == 0 && resultday == 0) {
    $(this).addClass("today");
}

$("li").click(function() {
    alert(resultyear + "," + resultmonth + "," + resultday);
});

});
```

This jQuery function just finds all li.event elements and then does some math and lets us know if the date within the `<time>` is older or newer than today's date.

The jQuery just pumps out the current date, formats it like the `<time>` date attribute, and then subtracts everything.  Then, based on the results, adds an "old" "new" or "today" class to each element.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, so I thought about it on my drive home last night.  I've cleaned up the code a bit.  There was also a piece I didn't take into account which is fixed in the code in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ekd25L8/4/

Comment: Wow that's fantastic--thank you! I'll give this a try, as well.